# How to release a lock and acquire another atomicly

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In my application I manage a collection of locks that I need to serialize access to some of objects (each object is assigned a lock). This collection of locks (lock manager) also needs to be maintained in a thread-safe fashion (new locks are added/old locks are removed as new objects which require serialization are added/removed).
The algorithm works something like this:

```
LockManager.Lock();
var myLock = LockManager.FindLock(myObject);
LockManager.Unlock();                          // atomic
myLock.Lock();                                 // atomic
```

Swapping two lines is not a good solution. If locking of `myLock` would block then this would also block unlocking of `LockManager` making any requests for other locks to block.

What I would need is that the two marked lines are executed atomically. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: why not just take the lock before unlocking the manager?

Comment: Why not just use another lock. The makethisactionatomic lock.

Comment: @CodeInChaos:
If the other lock blocks then the release of the first lock is also blocked for that duration.

Comment: @CodingBarfield
This would be one solution, I thought that .NET might have some better solution for this in the framework.

Comment: @dcarapic your manager and object locks shall be independant, swap two last lines, if you cannot do that then you might have a bug in the code. Pls post the code for locking and unlocking for manager and objects.

Comment: @oleksii
Swapping two lines is not a good solution. If locking of myLock would block then this would also block unlocking of LockManager making any requests for other locks to block:

LockManager.Lock();
var myLock = LockManager.FindLock(myObject);
myLock.Lock();        // if this blocks because lock is already taken
LockManager.Unlock(); // then this will also be blocked

Comment: @dcarapic Yeah, you are right. But the solution with another lock suggested by @CodingBarfield would work either. See the code: `LockManager.Lock();
var myLock = LockManager.FindLock(myObject);  
lock(synchRoot) //yet another lock
{
    LockManager.Unlock(); // unlocks for next thread
    myLock.Lock(); // if this blocks first time, next second thread cannot get the 2 instance lock
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to:

- guarantee that the individual lock (via `myLock`) was entered
- then unlock the `LockManager`
- make the above two operations atomic
- and not allow this new atomic operation to block if the individual lock cannot be entered immediately

Similar to how you cannot circumvent the laws of physics to create a perpetual motion machine you also cannot circumvent the laws of computation by executing a sequence of operations atomically in such manner that it does not block even if one of its constituents can, in fact, be expected to block. In other words, there is no way to make the operation complete until the individual parts also complete.

However, what we can do is attempt this atomic operation in an all-or-none manner that never blocks as long as we are okay with the "none" outcome. You see this a lot with the `TryXXX` methods that exist on a lot of concurrent data structures. All you would need to do is define a `TryLock` on your `myLock` type. Then, the `LockManager` could look like the following.

```
public class LockManager
{
  public bool TryEnterIndividualLock(object value)
  {
    Lock();
    try
    {
      var myLock = FindLock(value);
      if (myLock != null)
      {
        return myLock.TryLock();
      }
      return false;
    }
    finally
    {
      Unlock();
    }
  }  
}
```

Then the calling code would look like this:

```
while (!LockManager.TryEnterIndividualLock(myObject))
{
  // Do something else until the lock can be entered.
}
```

This would give you the atomicity you were looking for, but at the cost of the operation not succeeding. If you are relying on this operation succeeding immediately then you are going to have to rethink your overall design.